# Testing Django FileResponse

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django view that returns a file. The `FileResponse` is built for that purpose. However, I do not understand how to test this.

Right now I use the `HttpResponse` and test it like this:

```py
response = client.get(url)
io = io = BytesIO(response.content)
```

The `io` object can now be used for further testing.

However, if I try the following with `FileResponse` (which is derived from `StreamingHttpResponse` and thus has `streaming_content` instead of `content`), I get the following exception:

`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'map'`

If I cast the `map` object to `bytes` like this:

```py
response = client.get(url)
io = io = BytesIO(bytes(response.streaming_content))
```

I get another exception: `TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

How can I get an `BytesIO` object from `FileResponse.streaming_content`?

Comment: `streaming_content()` is an iterator of strings, so you should iterate over it. Actually you can iterate over the response directly (`__iter__()` is defined as `self.streaming_content`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

streaming_content is iterable, not bytestring, so you will have to join them.

```
fileres = bytes("test", 'utf-8')
stream = b''.join(response.streaming_content)
assert stream == fileres
```

Answer (score 1):

response.getvalue() is responsible to convert from map to bytes:

```
from io import BytesIO
bytes_io = BytesIO(response.getvalue())
```

Comment: For anyone else who didn't know off hand, `BytesIO` is in the `io` module:
```from io import BytesIO```